# What is LOG(INFO) and LOG(ERROR) doing?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, terminal

I try to run [this C++ example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc) from tensorflow. It is compiling and I don't get any error message while running the program. Unfortunately I also don't get any output in the terminal. The main function calls the function `PrintTopLabels(outputs, labels)` to print the results. Reading through it the function writes all messages into a `LOG(INFO)` object. But I can't find any explanation what this is doing exactly.

What am I missing here? Why can't I get any output?

I added some `std::cout` messages, which are displayed when I run the program.

Comment: That's probably a macro, and if it is, it's defined in a header file. Look it up.

Comment: You're looking at one file of many.  The `LOG` macros are defined [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/platform/default/logging.h).

Answer (score 0):

They are part of the Glog library. You can print the messages to stderr by defining the GLOG_alsologtostderr environment variable when you run your program...

```
$ GLOG_alsologtostderr=1 ./<your_program_name>
```

Additionally, if your program is built with the Gflags library, you can pass a command line flag instead...

```
$ ./<your_program_name> --alsologtostderr
```